# "wrap it in a bufio.NewReader if it doesn't support ReadByte" pattern

Tags: go

Following is a snippet from one of the Go libs. Could anyone please point out the significance of `r.(byteReader)`? The syntax usage is not very obvious to a novice. `byteReader` is a defined interface and does not seem to be the member of `io.Reader`. Since, this seems to be some kind of nifty code, can anyone provide some insight.

The author mentions: "wrap it in a bufio.NewReader if it doesn't support ReadByte" pattern. https://github.com/dave-andersen/deltagolomb/blob/master/deltagolomb.go

```
type byteReader interface {
    io.Reader
    ReadByte() (c byte, err error)
}

func makeReader(r io.Reader) byteReader {
    if rr, ok := r.(byteReader); ok {
        return rr
    }
    return bufio.NewReader(r)
}
```

Comment: @Ainar-G They differ slightly in whether you assert to another interface (as in this case) or to a non-interface type (as in the other question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r.(byteReader)` is called a *type assertion*. Even if `io.Reader` doesn't implement the `byteReader` interface in itself, it it still possible that the value stored in `r` might implement `byteReader`. So, by doing the type assertion, you can assert if that is the case:

[The specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) states:

> x.(T) asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of
>   type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>   ...
>   If T is
>   an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x implements
>   the interface T.

**Edit**

The comment, *"wrap it in a bufio.NewReader"*, refers to `makeReader`'s provided `io.Reader`; if it doesn't implement `byteReader`, `makeReader` will wrap it in a `bufio.Reader` which does implement `bytesReader`, and return it instead.